# Linking to visual studio dynamic library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, dynamic-linking

I am trying to create a dynamic library and use it in a console application. The library is `Multisite.lib`.

My problem is that when I add the project as a reference and add the header files directory it works well, however, when I try to use this library in an independent project I get the `unresolved external symbol` error.

What I did in the independent project is to add the library to the **Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies** and add the header directories

```
#pragma once

#ifndef MultiSite_IMPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#define STACKMODE   __stdcall

#include <string>

struct interfaceManager;

MATHLIBRARY_API interfaceManager* STACKMODE createInstance();

MATHLIBRARY_API void STACKMODE bert_init(interfaceManager * inst , int bid);

MATHLIBRARY_API bool STACKMODE bert_connect(interfaceManager * inst, std::string IP);
```

These are the functions that I am trying to export and that are considered unresolved external symbols

**EDIT**
I tried to use the VS developer tools using `dumpbin /EXPORTS MultiSite.lib` and all my functions are there

[image: Using Visual Studio cmd]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using a **64-bit** library on a **32-bit** application.
That's why it was working fine when I added it to the same solution but not in my independent project.

I used to think that visual studio can detect a wrong format but turns out that just the exported symbol's names change between two same libraries with different bit configuration.

Hence this explains the `unresolved external symbol` error that I encountered

Comment: That is why I was asking about other errors. In this case usually Visual Studio will add a linker error that says can not open `Multisite.lib`

Answer (score 0):

The header doesn't contain the magic line needed to make Visual Studio link the right library. That's `#pragma comment(lib, "MultiSite.lib")`. It goes after `#define MATHLIBRARY_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)`.

Alternatively, you can indeed tell the linker directly that `MultiSite.lib` is an additional input. See the Visual Studio linker property pages of your executable project.

Comment: In the question it says ***add the library to the Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies*** I think more info is needed in the question. Perhaps the exact text of the errors

Comment: @drescherjm The text of the error is `unresolved external symbol createInstance` and the other two functions.

Comment: @MSalters The things is that I already made another library using similar class but I never used `#pragma comment(lib, "MultiSite.lib")` and it's working fine

Comment: Yes for each of the three symbols

Comment: Did you define the preprocessor symbol `MultiSite_IMPORTS` so `MATHLIBRARY_API` is `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)`

Answer (score 0):

**"What I did in the independent project is to add the library to the Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies and add the header directories"**

As far as I'm concerned, the project lacks `MultiSite.lib`. I suggest you should add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories).

Comment: I did add the library path but the problem was that the library's output is a x64 configuration library whereas the independent project was configured to x86. I thought that visual studio usually tells you that it is wrong format or something. Never knew that it compiles as undefined symbols.